# Passing variables between files in Python

Tags: python

I am quite new to python but I have been given some code by a group project teammate that I need to integrate with my own code. The main programme is contained in a main.py file which imports variables from a settings.py file. main.py also imports functions from functions.py file. functions.py also imports variables from settings.py. My own code requires iteration so I need to be able to change the settings.py variables when running main.py to solve the problem. Ideally I can find a way to adjust my teammates code to become a function that I can simply pass variables into and out of.

I have tried to import variables from main.py to settings.py but that results in cyclic importing. I can't find any solutions and not for lack of trying and would really appreciate any help.

```
main.py
import settings
import function
settings.x=10
print(settings.x+function.y)


settings.py
x=1

function.py
import settings
y= settings.x
```

Effectively I want this to print out 20 and not 11.

Comment: How could we help without seeing your code?

Comment: _**"My own code requires iteration so I need to be able to change the settings.py variables when running main.py to solve the problem."**_ - Could you please elaborate on this claim more, and provide a [mcve]? Your problem sounds a bit like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem.

Comment: I've added some code which hopefully explains my problem better.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can use `import settings` to import `settings.py`, but it sounds like you're planning to (ab)use a code file as a data file.

If the goal is to allow for changing settings quickly between runs, or even to modify the data over the course of multiple iterations, you should absolutely consider using a different file format for the settings.

A good option would be using `.json`. For example:

main.py:

```
import json

settings = json.load(open('settings.json'))

print(settings)
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "some_setting": 1,
    "some_list": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "nested_stuff": {
        "message": "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Note that a `.json` file looks a lot like a Python dictionary, but you need to use double quotes and there are some other specific restrictions.

Using `json` is especially convenient if you want to update the file from your code as well, for example:

```
import json

with open('settings.json') as f:
    settings = json.load(f)

settings['some_setting'] += 1

with open('settings.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(settings, f)
```